# Swipe does not work in second activity

Tags: android, swipe, kotlin

Swipe does not work in second activity:
I create two activities and use [swipe library](https://github.com/pwittchen/swipe).
First activity swipes well, but second doesn't work.
Here some piece of code:

```
 private var _swipe: Swipe = Swipe();

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1)
    _swipe.addListener(object :SwipeListener {
         override fun onSwipedLeft(event: MotionEvent?) {
            val intent = Intent(this@FirstActivity,SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

The second activity have the same code, but it named `second_activity`.
Swipe in first activity works well, it redirects to second, but then swipe does'n work! Not to left, not to right and so on.

Can you help me?

Second activity:

```
   public class SecondActivity :  MvpActivity<ISecondView, SecondPresenter>   (),ISecondView  {

private var _manager: PlayerManager = PlayerManager();
/**
 * Instantiate a presenter instance

 * @return The [MvpPresenter] for this view
 */
override fun createPresenter(): SelectPresenter {
    return SecondPresenter(_manager);
}

private var _swipe: Swipe = Swipe();
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_2)

    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

    val players = realm.where(Player::class.java).findAll()


    val arrayList = ArrayList<String>(players.size)
    for (player in players) {

            arrayList.add(player.Name);            
    }


    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, arrayList)

    val lvArr = findViewById(R.id.ListView) as ListView;
    lvArr.choiceMode= ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE;
    lvArr.adapter = adapter

    lvArr.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView: AdapterView<*>, view1: View, i: Int, l: Long ->
        //select elem
    }

    _swipe.addListener(object : SwipeListener {           
        override fun onSwipedLeft(event: MotionEvent?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "swiped left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            val intent=  Intent(this@SecondfActivity,ThirdActivity::class.java);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        override fun onSwipingLeft(event: MotionEvent?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "swiping left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            val intent=  Intent(this@SecondActivity,ThirdActivity::class.java);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
})
}
}
```

I remove some methods implementations. When i try to swipe- nothing happens.

Comment: please show code of the second activity

Comment: @maxost,i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an author of the library you're using.
Are you sure you're overriding `dispatchTouchEvent(event)` method and calling a `swipe.dispatchTouchEvent(event)` method inside it in both activities? You haven't mentioned it in the code snippets, but it's required to make everything work.

```
  override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    (swipe as Swipe).dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
  }
```

3 steps regarding library configuration are described in `README.md` file on GitHub.

Regards,

Piotr

Comment: Thank you! i miss it! My fail!

Comment: Great! Maybe I'll think of some kind of generic or exemplary unit tests to avoid such human mistakes in the future.